# installation symfony unknown command symfony init-app testapp

Tags: php, command-line, symfony-1.4, init

I had install `symfony` on window, i have done follow by [this](http://www.poetryofprogramming.com/symfony/install-symfony-framework-xp-vista-wamp/) but in end i meet problem because it's not recognize with `symfony init-app myapp` command . Any one can help me please

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Link you provided seems to be quite old and valid for older versions of Symfony than 1.4. In Symfony 1.4 valid commands to use in your case are:

```
symfony generate:project
symfony generate:app
```

Comment: with this command i also try already but it's also unknown `symfony generate:app`

Comment: just ensuring: are you using `php symfony generate:app` (with `php` prefix) ?

Comment: i try both of it `symfony generate:app` and `php symfony generate:app` but it's return the same message: `Task "init-app" is not defined.`

Comment: try `php symfony` - it will display list of all available tasks